# Declining an industry job oppurtunity

Tags: undergraduate, industry, interpersonal-issues

I was recently forwarded a job opening for a company with which my PI has research ties.

The job role and function itself does not appeal to me. I am quite keen on applying for grad schools that are directed more towards my own interests and cannot take the time out to work at this place as well. I don’t want to jeopardize my relationship with my PI since I really like working with them, but I want to turn down this offer, respectfully.

I would truly appreciate how I can communicate this with them.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Dear Prof. P,
>
> Thank you for forwarding information to me on the job opening at Company C for role R.
>
> However, I would like to mention that the role itself, on *<research topic T1>*, is a little distant from my research interests. I wish to work more on the lines of *<research topic T2>*, as I have done in your lab over the last one year. Further, I am planning to apply for graduate studies soon, in topics similar to *<topic T2>*.
>
> Hence, I request you not to forward my application for this job opening.
>
> Regards,
>
> AP_98

I think this should work.

Most reasonable professors will not be offended by a request like this, as long as you are being honest and open about it.

Comment: Isn't that a bit too verbose? Also, there is no indication that the prof intended to forward the application to the company. Maybe it was just intended as "FYI" to OP. Depending on whether the prof expects a response or not, I would either write nothing or just a very short mail indicating that will check  the ad if it is suitable for their future plans (without, at this stage, already saying that this is not suitable; if the prof asks later, they can say that, after consideration, that was not a suitable position for them, or something like that).

Comment: @CaptainEmacs True, but the OP did mention that they wanted to _"let the professor know, not to forward the application."_ I wrote the answer assuming that the professor forwarded the job opening knowingly, perhaps even expecting the OP to apply. At least, the tone of the question made me feel that.

Comment: Maybe the OP can correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: @Ram Padmanabhan, Thank you so much for providing me with this response! My PI did forward me this email asking, if I would be interested in applying for the position he sent me. I just had paraphrase your response a little is all. But I essentially wanted to respond in a similar vein to your response. Thank you so much for your help!